# How thick are Dominion cards?

Tags: dominion, playing-cards

I want to design custom laser-cut boxes to hold my Dominion sets, and I need to calculate how big a box is needed for each expansion. I can easily get the card dimensions online for height and width (91mm x 59mm), but if I'm going to put 500 cards in a box, I need to know how thick the stack will be.

I can't seem to find dimensions on the thickness of a stack. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did a measurement of my fairly well played dominion cards.

When allowed to float up, a stack of 50 cards is 23/32 of an inch tall. I tried different combinations to account for imperfections and came to this number multiple times in various trials.

When compressed with a gentle hand to maximum compression, they compress to 21/32 of an inch for 50 cards.

Thus if you were to have a box holding 500 cards I would expect them to be at absolute minimum 210/32 of an inch, or 6 9/16 inches. If we allow for comfortable float compression that would take us to 7 3/16 of an inch. Since you'll want at least some wiggle room, I would suggest making your **500 card box of dominion 7 inches long**. Keeping in mind that 500 cards is 50 types, you may want to calculate extra room for things like placeholders, extra cards, separators, etc.

Comment: My intention was to make one box per base/expansion, and size the box to the expansion size, less the base cards. So the "Dominion" set would be sized for 292 cards (more likely 300), which would be the 500 total cards, less the 208 base cards (Copper/Silver/Gold/Estate/Duchy/Province). Take out the 32 randomizers, and the 7 blank cards and there should be enough wiggle-room, even with 25 separators.

Comment: @BuddhaBuck Don't forget that Potion, Colony, and Platinum are also basic cards even though you don't play with them in every game.  There are 16 Potions and 12 each of Colony and Platinum.  If you ever need to buy a replacement [Base Cards set](http://riograndegames.com/Game/419-Dominion-Base-cards), it comes with these in addition to the other 7 basic card types.

Comment: As for the basic cards, if you count the Trash card and the above 3 sets, there are 249 of them: 30 Curse, 24 Estate, 12 Duchy, 12 Province, 12 Colony, 60 Copper, 40 Silver, 30 Gold, 12 Platinum, 16 Potion, 1 Trash.

Comment: The idea is to create a box per expansion (counting the base set as an "Expansion") and trays to store the basic cards. I already bought the replacement Base Cards set (so I have three sets of copper/silver/gold/estate/duchy/province/curse, and two sets of potions/colony/platinum) because I like the art better. I will build a bigger outer box to hold the per-set boxes.